# FreeBSD: Getting pkg_add to use stable packages rather than release packages?

Tags: freebsd, package-management, upgrade, bsd-ports

Using FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE.  I want to use the latest binary packages rather than the packages at the time of the 8.2 release.  That is, I want to use packages in ftp://ftp2.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-8-stable/All/ rather than ftp://ftp2.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-8.2-release/All/.

I'm not interested in compiling a bunch of stuff so I don't want to simply upgrade ports and then be forced to compile everything.  For compiling small things it's ok, but I don't want to wait hours to get some of the bigger programs.

How can I get my system to use the stable binary packages (and upgrade ports so everything is in sync)?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/packages-using.html

"If you want to force pkg_add(1) to download FreeBSD 8-STABLE packages, set PACKAGESITE to ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-8-stable/Latest/."

Note that you will eventually get some brokenness unless you also track STABLE in your base installation.

Ports must be updated separately via, say, portsnap fetch && portsnap update.

Comment: When you say "track STABLE in your base installation", what do you mean by that?

Comment: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/current-stable.html

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I've used FreeBSD, but it looks like you mean `pkg_add -r <package>`?

As far as I can tell, `pkg_add` is defaulting to a URL based on `uname -r`.

So perhaps you should upgrade the base system using the instructions in the handbook (e.g. [Rebuilding "world"](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/makeworld.html).

Or maybe the PACKAGESITE, PACKAGEROOT, and PKG_ADD_BASE environment variables can help?

Comment: basically I mean if possible, getting my 8.2-RELEASE system to use 8-STABLE pacakages (yes using pkg_add -r).  But also I want my ports upgraded to stable so I can compile if I want to and all versions match.